# Force Airport Express to join 5GHz network

Tags: wifi, airport

I have an Airport Express 2nd Generation (Version 7.6.8) that I'm using as an access point for my desktop PC.

My house has a Technicolor DPC3848VE modem and WiFi router with dual-band network.

I set the Airport express to connect to the 5GHz network (the networks have the same name + 2.4 or 5.0 for differentiating them).

All the connection is done without problems, but when I check the Network Icon in the Task Bar, the tooltip says I’m connected to the 2.4GHz network.

[image]

Just to be sure I did a factory reset and connected the router again and it still connects me to the 2.4GHz network.

How can I fix this/force the airport to only use the 5GHz network?

Comment: I am confused, do you want your PC to connect to the Airport's 5GHz network or the Airport to connect to your router's 5GHz network?

Comment: @Allan I want the airport express, which I use as Access Point, to connect to my router's 5.0 wifi, instead of the 2.4

Comment: Which task bar are you clicking on?  can you provide a screen shot?

Comment: @Allan the icon about the network in the bottom right.
I know the airport detects the 5GHZ because that's the one I setted up, but when it finish configurating it shows this: https://snag.gy/Oda5BX.jpg

Comment: The picture you posted is your PC connecting to your WAP (assuming Airport Express), not the Airport Express connecting to your router.  What does it say in your Airport Utility?

Comment: The setup says it's connected to the 5GHz network, but it's speed is one of 2.4Ghz. (I have a lot of problems with 2.4 so when I used 5.0 it worked wonderfull). Also the fact that WAP says 2.4 gives me more doubt about.
[This post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3978814?tstart=0) has a solution, but I can't shut down the 2.4 GHz connection.

Answer (score 1):

Your computer will use the wifi best suited under current reception characteristics. If you want to force your windows computer to only use the 5GHz wifi, you'll have to remove the 2.4 GHz from the known networks as for example detailed here for Windows 10 (which you appear to be using judging by your screenshot): http://www.ilovefreesoftware.com/24/windows-10/remove-saved-wi-fi-networks-windows-10.html

What you could do is configure both wifi's with the same name and let your computer switch automatically (works way better when they have the same name), that way your laptop would choose the 5 GHz one when close enough to the Airport and choose the 2.4 GHz one when further away

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. I'm using the Airport Express as a Wifi Receiver, I have a Desktop PC which does not have a wifi card.

Comment: if that is the case, then I'm confused. LAN connections don't have network names. And there is no way you could connect an Airport Express via USB to use it as a "wifi stick". So I don't know what you're showing in your screenshot then.

Comment: i'm connecting it through the ethernet port and using the Airport software to make it work as a wireless bridge.

Comment: Did you try being very close to the router? 5GHz's propagation characteristics are way shorter than the ones from 2.4 GHz. Also, did you consider having one wifi name for both the 5 and 2.4 GHz networks and let the airport switch automatically?